# Put div in between images

Tags: css, image, html, position

I have 5 images and one `div` with text. Html looks like this:

```
<div id="title">Title of gallery</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="thumbs/1.jpg"/>
    <img src="thumbs/2.jpg"/>
    <img src="thumbs/3.jpg"/>
    <img src="thumbs/4.jpg"/>
    <img src="thumbs/5.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I can put my `#title` inside `#gallery` if it helps, but not in between images. Only before/after them.

Picture worth more than 1000 words, so here is what I want to achieve:

[image: div with text between images]

This is my current CSS for images (nothing more, I've just started):

```
#page img {
    border:none;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

I'm also using [inuitCSS](http://csswizardry.com/inuitcss/) here, so maybe it can help with my problem somehow.

Comment: +1 for showing us the [Hermann-grid illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_illusion)

Comment: @pinouchon Wanted to add a little bit of magic to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some CSS shenanigans for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/5qzXV/

Comment: @smogg: I use placekitten ALL THE TIME now - boring old placeholders just won't do :)